# how do i read each param with npapi

Tags: delphi, npapi

iam using npapi frame work inside my Delphi  project , iam able to read params with this current code

```
procedure TDemoPluginForm.btTestClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  obj: IBrowserObject;
  res: TStringList;
  items, n: IBrowserObject;
  i: integer;
begin
  res:=TStringList.Create;
  try
    res.Add('Plugin element details:');
    // Get object of plugin element
    obj:=Plugin.GetPluginObject;
    // Get element property
    res.Add('id=' + string(obj['id']));
    // Get child elements
    res.Add('Child nodes:');
    items:=obj.GetObject('childNodes');
    for i:=0 to items['length'] - 1 do begin
      n:=VarAsObject(items.Invoke('item', [i]));
      if CompareText(n['tagName'], 'param') = 0 then
        res.Add(Format('Tag: %s; Name: %s; Value: %s',
                      [string(n['tagName']),
                       string(n['name']),
                       string(n['value'])
                       ]));
    end;
    MessageBox(Self.Handle, PChar(res.Text), PChar('Delphi Plugin'), MB_ICONINFORMATION);
  finally
    res.Free;
  end;
end;
```

how could i read each param with its reference .

to be more specific if i have param like this

```
  <param name = "delphi" value = "student" />
```

how could i read inside delphi if param = delphi then somestring := its value ?

Comment: i try to parse it to store some local variable

Comment: Small sidenote: http://blog.chromium.org/2014/11/the-final-countdown-for-npapi.html

Comment: yes npapi will be down in September sadly :(

Comment: i tried for example var

name :string;

   `if CompareText(n['tagName'], 'param') = username then

name := string(n['name']);` but its empty

Comment: you are using comparetext the wrong way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the answer in your reach, you can use [`System.SysUtils.SameText`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.SameText) to achieve your goal:

```
procedure TDemoPluginForm.btTestClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  obj: IBrowserObject;
  res: TStringList;
  items, n: IBrowserObject;
  i: integer;
  value : String;

begin
  res:=TStringList.Create;
  try
    res.Add('Plugin element details:');
    // Get object of plugin element
    obj:=Plugin.GetPluginObject;
    // Get element property
    res.Add('id=' + string(obj['id']));
    // Get child elements
    res.Add('Child nodes:');
    items:=obj.GetObject('childNodes');
    for i:=0 to items['length'] - 1 do begin
      n:=VarAsObject(items.Invoke('item', [i]));
      if SameText(n['tagName'], 'param') then
       begin 
        res.Add(Format('Tag: %s; Name: %s; Value: %s',
                      [string(n['tagName']),
                       string(n['name']),
                       string(n['value'])
                       ]));
        if SameText(n['name'], 'delphi') then
         value := String(n['value']);
      end;
    end;
    MessageBox(Self.Handle, PChar(res.Text), PChar('Delphi Plugin'), MB_ICONINFORMATION);
  finally
    res.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: its says no overloaded version that can call this argument